# Access secure Geoserver WMS from ArcGIS using LDAP Domain user

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoserver, wms, authentication

When I use public workspace:

http://(myserver):8080/geoserver/public/wms?

The layers are displayed in ArcMap, but when I switch to a private workspace (imagery_mp) using:

http://(myserver):8080/geoserver/imagery_mp/wms?
I put my credentials and I get: *No resource could be found at that address. (status code 404).*

**http://(domain/user:password@)(myserver):8080/geoserver/imagery_mp/wms?**
I get: *Internal server error. (status code 500).*

Then I try:
**http://(domain\user:password@)(myserver):8080/geoserver/imagery_mp/wms?**
I get: *No resource could be found at that address. (status code 404).*

Then I try:
**http://(myuser@mydomain.com:password@)(myserver):8080/geoserver/imagery_mp/wms?**
I get: *Unidentified error*

QGIS displays correctly using boxes for credentials, my setup is ArcMap 10.4 and GEOSERVER 2.11.1.

Comment: I couldn't use the format *user:password@* I have to install Auth module and give tokens to each user.